# Pandas any/all doesn't seem to return right results

Tags: python, pandas, any

I have the following dataframe:

```
test = 

    fa_count    dist_fa_count   dsc_count   dist_dsc_count
       0    63403.285714         1.0          1.0   1.0
       1    37837.285714         1.0          1.0   1.0
       2    9185.285714          1.0          1.0   1.0
       3    23729.142857         1.0          1.0   1.0
       4    22288.142857         1.0          1.0   1.0
       5    77365.000000         1.0          1.0   1.0
```

I want to return any index + row that has a value != 1 (i.e. every row in this case).

```
 test.all(1) == 1
```

returns  all true and

```
test.any(1) != 1
```

returns all false. Any idea why/another way?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: presumably you want something like `(test == 1).all(1)` and `(test!=1).any(1)`

Comment: Yep. That's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like

```
(test == 1).all(1)
```

and

```
(test != 1).any(1)
```